# Deleting the object and its mapping in one-to-many in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have 2 domain classes as follows -

```
class A {
   static hasMany = [B] // Just trying to show my mapping
}

class B {
   // This table doesn't belongs to A
}
```

**Now I have a object of class A which contains a set of objects B. I want to delete object A and its association with B, but I don't want to delete object B.**

I have tried cascade for delete, delete-all & delete-all-orphan but it seems to be trying to delete the associated records from table B which isn't what I want.

This is what I am doing right now -

```
objectTypeB.each { b ->
     a.removeFromB(b)
}
```

and then

```
a.delete()
```

but getting error

```
deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is almost correct, I think what you need is tell A what collection to store B's in (see the hasMany)

```
class A {
    String name
    static hasMany = [b: B]
}
class B {
    String name
}
```

Then it should be possible to do this (I tried it in a blank project, where my domains also have a String name property):

```
def b1 = new B(name: 'b1').save(flush: true)
def b2 = new B(name: 'b2').save(flush: true)
def b3 = new B(name: 'b3').save(flush: true)

def a = new A(name: 'a')
a.addToB(b1)
a.addToB(b2)
a.save(flush: true)

def x = A.get(1)

println x.b

x.delete(flush: true)
assert A.count() == 0
```

Since there is no relation from B to A, there is no need to remove the b's from A before deleting the A. If you want, I can send you my code sniplet

Comment: Hey @sbglasius,  I tried your suggestion but still getting this error -      org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations):

Comment: Also, my association had hasMany = [b: B], but I didn't show it to keep thing simple.  Can you please send me your code snippet ?

Comment: Alright, I found the issue after I followed your example. I was accessing the object A using someOtherDomain.A.delete(). After I used A.get() everything worked fine. I missed using get() and rather accessing from session.  Thanks a lot for your help !!!